# Add vertical scrollbar to TextEdit control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I am using a `TextEdit` control from DevExpress (v11.2) in a `GridControl` data template.

The content of the control is too long - 7000 characters - and I want a vertical scrollbar for the control. I have set `verticalscrollbarvisibility = true`, but the scrollbar is not visible. I am left with one very long row.

How can I force a vertical scrollbar on a `TextEdit` control?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to directly address the problem you're having, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also formatted your question, fixed some typos, and ended with a clear and direct summary of the question you are asking.

You are describing your code in the question, but if you include code your question will be well received and you are more likely to get helpful answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `VerticalScrollBar`, you should make sure that the text you are writing has line separators.
If there are no line delimiters, you can only use `HorizontalScrollBar`.
If you do not care about ScrollBar, but it's important that all the text fit, then you can use the property `TextWrapping =" Wrap "`.

Example code with a string without delimiters (only HorizontalScrollBar is available here):
[Example HorizontalScrollBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5H4r.png)

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="TempText1,TempText1,TempText1,TempText1,TempText1,TempText1,TempText1,TempText1"/>
</Grid>
```

Example code with a delimited string (VerticalScrollBar is already available here):
[Example VerticalScrollBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C2Hm.png)

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;something1&#x0a;"/>
</Grid>
```